# How to access html file using local host

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

Please I need help with accessing my html/php file with localhost on my browser,i turn my xampp on and tried to access my html/php file,but it is still not working
[That's what I keep getting everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBUrb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The path component of the URL to your file starts at the directory specified in the `DocumentRoot` configuration option for your Apache HTTPD server. This probably defaults to the `htdocs` directory.

It doesn't start at the root of your filesystem. Web servers do not, by default, expose every file on your hard disk to the network (which would be a scary default for security reasons).

Comment: So what do you suggest I do now?

Comment: @Adeyemijoshua — Remove the bits from the path you are typing into the address bar which aren't under the document root!

Comment: Still not working ☹️

Comment: It is still giving thesame result "Not found!"

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't have to enter xampp/htdocs in the link. localhost is reffering to your xampp htdocs folder "automatically". Try localhost/phpinvscode

If you put your index.html file in the htdocs folder directly you would only need to enter localhost in the browser.

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: Hm that's weird, so you have a folder called phpinvscode inside your htdocs folder  and in this folder the index.html, am I right? So normally if there is nothing else configured it should be accessable (if Apache is started) via http://localhost/phpinvscode/  this should call the index.html inside the folder phpinvscode.

Comment: Let me try the whole process again and see if it works